# Error while running a SSIS package with SQL JOBS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

i am using SSIS , visual studio 2017 . 
cant find a solution to my problem anywhere.
i deployed a package that has 3 children that they are also packages , inside each package there are sql tasks and data flows that imports a databases to my own data base. 
**if i run this SQL JOB manually** it works , if i set a job to a certin time i get errors.

what could be the problem?

following errors:
0xC0012050
DLN1 Error: 0xC0208449
0x80070003
[image]
**there is an error uploading an image with the errors **

i searched the web but there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is right ther in the error message: "Login failed for user bytes2story". When you configure a job step an tell it to execute a SSIS package, you can provide a user as which the execution of the package should be performed. Most certainly the user you chose is lacking privileges. Check the privileges of the user bytestostory or choose another user.

Comment: how do i check the privileges?

Comment: but i am admin ? how could i have not have a permission

Comment: Yes, YOU have admin rights. That's the reason why YOU can run the package. But if you execute it via schedule, the user is most certainly another one - that is if you didn't create a technical user with your privileges and admin rights on the corresponding server!?

Comment: ok i understand , but how can i give sql agent permission? @Tyron78

Comment: also how do u explain that when i run other packages with sql jobs it works perfectly

Comment: So, do the other - working - packages access all the same sources / destinations as the failing one does? I suggest to compare if there are any databases, servers or filesystems which only this package accesses and check the privileges there.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a package that contains other packages then there is a problem.
the solution is to run all packages that have dataflows(without other packages) by them self.

for some reason SSIS cant handle packages with children

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).